# hiding list tag with display none doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, display

I'm making an app using **Telerik platfom** which uses html, css, and javascript. And I have some questions about html code.

```
<body>
 <li>
  switch on/off<input data-role="switch" checked="checked" data-change="onChange"/>
 </li>

 <li class="switch-on">
  end:<input type="time" id="switch-on-end-time"></input>
 </li>

 <li class="switch-off" style="display:none">
  start:<input type="time" id="switch-off-start-time"></input>
 </li>
 <li class="switch-off" style="display:none">
  end:<input type="time" id="switch-off-end-time"></input>
 </li>

 <script>
 function onChange (e) {
    isSwitchOn = e.checked;
    const switchOff = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-off');
    const switchOn = document.getElementsByClassName('switch-on');
    if(e.checked) {
        for (let el of switchOff) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
        for (let el of switchOn) {
            el.style.display = 'list-item'
        }
    } else {
        for (let el of switchOn) {
            el.style.display = 'none';
        }
        for (let el of switchOff) {
            el.style.display = 'list-item'
        }
    }
 }
 </script>
</body>
```

When I use telerik simulation device it works well, but when I execute in my phone(Iphone 6 - version 10.21.1) it doesn't work. Specifically, when I switch off the button, nothing changes and that means display attribute doesn't change. Is this only phone problem or do I have some mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like, that you've made an error in your code. Try changing this:

```
<li>
switch on/off<input data-role="switch" checked="checked" data-change="onChange"/>
</li>
```

To this:

```
<li>
<input data-role="switch" checked="checked" data-change="onChange">switch on/off</input>
</li>
```

I haven't tested it, - and I'm not 100% sure that that is it. It might be working in a computer-browser (and not on your phone-browser), since computer-browsers are a bit more clever still.

But you could try to install IE6 and then nothing would work, - so I guess it's not just on your Iphone. :-)

Comment: I find the answer. When I use jQuery .show() and .hide() method, it works well! I think the problem is telerik platform was the real problem. Thanks